# Could not save .mp4 video file to iphone camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, media, camera-roll

I received the video file contents in the format of NSData and I am playing that file in MPMoviePlayerController successfully with following code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *FileExtension=[[NSString alloc]init];

if([contentType hasPrefix:@"video"] || [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/video"]) {
    FileExtension=@"mov";
   //FileExtension=@"mp4";
}
else
{
  FileExtension=[contentType lastPathComponent];
}

 //appFile is type of NSString.
 appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyFile.%@",FileExtension]];

//videoData is type of NSData
[videoData writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES]; 

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appFile isDirectory:NO];

moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
moviePlayerController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
moviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay=NO;

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
```

but I am unable to write/save this video file to camera roll,this is my code for writing code to the camera roll.

```
  ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appFile isDirectory:NO];
  if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:filePathURL]) {
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:filePathURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Not success");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"success");
        }
    }];

}
```

this code is work fine when I set mimeType/file_format as .mov & .3Gp but I have problem related to save video to the camera roll when mimeType/file_format as .mp4 file.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your .mp4 to .mov if you change your appFile this way:

Your code:

```
 appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyFile.%@",FileExtension]];
```

New code:

```
 appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.mov"];
```

The SO automatically converts .mp4 to .mov